# Elastic beanstalk web API not finding files

Tags: asp.net, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have created a web API in .Net that has two file paths to certificate files and one file path to a .CSV which will be logged by the application.

I get no errors publishing to elastic beanstalk and the web API works perfectly on the localhost. However, when I try to access the published web api (on eb), I get the following error `"ExceptionMessage": "The system cannot find the path specified.\r\n"`. The stack trace seems to show a problem specifically with the .p12 file.

Here is the filepath referenced in the C# code.  `new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Users\User\source\repos\EBS_web\EBS_web\App_Data\my256.p12", "password");`